# Self-sustainment

Tags: technology, communication, internet

In world I am talking about everyone vanished but two people. Everyone just dissapeared, like no body has been left. I have them contact via internet but then I realize; there is noone to tend servers. So, I have to explain how servers survive. Electricity can be provided by water generators, but how long can servers last? They should be able to survive nature around them and that includes animals. let's assume satelites can relay inforamtion to wherever and  strong enough to be picked up. Where should be servers to withstand year or more?
edit:this question is not asking about how long internet would survive *in its current state*, but rather I ask how to arrange it to survive longest time possible. It doesn't need numerical answer, but place and idea. what materials to use? what type of drives? Maybe ones that aren't widely used? Where to put servers so they survive against elements?

Answer (score 2):

**The Svalbard Global Seed Vault.**

[image: Svalbard Global Seed Vault]
https://3blmedia.com/News/Where-World-Stores-Its-Seeds-Svalbard-Global-Seed-Vault

It is at the end of the earth.  It is meant to survive the collapse of human society, and help us with the rebuilding.  It has seeds but it also must have power.

In your story you can make this what you need to be.  Detect the communications of the Seed Bank server with its satellite and repurpose its connections to be a sort of internet.  Probably a lot of things will be missing.  But maybe a lot of things will still be accessible.